# Logcat Doesn't work properly. why?

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-studio-3.0

Logcat only appears inside the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`. I'm trying to use the `Log (TAG, "msg");` within a class, and no log appears. why? in `MainActivity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("Test", "test");
}
```

It works!

But this class doesn't work:

```
public class Imgpixel {
    private static final String TAG = "Quicknotes";

    public Imgpixel() {

    }
    String src="C:\\path_of_image\\img.jpg";
    Mat imgRead = Imgcodecs.imread(src, IMREAD_COLOR);

    int lin = imgRead.rows(); //get the number of rows
    int col = imgRead.cols(); //get the number of cols

    List<double[]> pixels=new ArrayList<>();//arraylist to save array rgb below

    public void cor() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                double [] rgb = imgRead.get(i, j);
                pixels.add(0, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_but in another class don't work_" Please post a [mcve] of that.

Comment: Can you confirm that the method is executed? Try placing a breakpoint on the line in question.

Comment: I edited the code above.

Comment: Could you post the code responsible for calling the method 'cor()'?

Comment: Also `Log.v("TAG", "test")` will give you "TAG" in the logcat and not "Quicknotes" as I expect you actually wanted.

Comment: I have not yet created the code that will call the color method ()

Comment: I put the rest of the Imgpixel class code. but I do not understand why I can not see any logcat I've created. the void method does not return nor logcat?

Comment: Please do not create a new  `Imgpixel` class in the initializer! Do not do this :: `pubic Imgpixel(){ Imgpixel imgpixel = new Imgpixel();  imgpixel.cor(); }`  You will continue to create new Imgpixel objects indefinitely.

Comment: Ah understood! I can use this to call the method if I'm going to use it in another class, right?

Comment: Yes, this way `Imgpixel` class is a "module"  that you can repeatedly use anywhere and anytime you need. I hope this has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised your code example would compile. In your `Imgpixel` class the method `cor()` is defined outside the class, the variable `pixels` wouldn't be accessible and you have an extra `}`.

Call your `cor` method from another class (eg. from inside `MainActivity`) like this:

```
Imgpixel imgPixel = new Imgpixel();
imgPixel.cor();
```

When your `Imgpixel` class looks like this:

```
 public class Imgpixel{
    private static final String TAG = "Quicknotes";

    String src="C:\\path_of_image\\img.jpg";
    Mat imgRead = Imgcodecs.imread(src, IMREAD_COLOR);

    int lin = imgRead.rows(); //get the number of rows
    int col = imgRead.cols(); //get the number of cols

    List<double[]> pixels=new ArrayList<>();

    public Imgpixel(){
        // initializing
    }

    public void cor() {
        Log.v(TAG, "test"); //Remove the quotation marks from TAG in order to get value from the variable you set earlier
        for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                double [] rgb = imgRead.get(i, j);
                pixels.add(0, rgb);
            }
        }
    }

} //this marks the end of the Imgpixel class
```

But you can also make `Imgpixel` a static class.

Comment: I may have copied with "{" wrong. In my code is correct, the "cor ()" method is within the class.

Comment: another question as I do to visualize what is saved inside the arraylist "pixels"? have any way to do this on android?

Comment: I created the class object and called the color () method like this:
public class Imgpixel {
// variables
}
public Imgpixel () {
Imgpixel imgpixel = new Imgpixel ();
imgpixel.cor ();

}
public void color () {
// method
}

Comment: my logs don't appear. Only appear inside of onCreate method, why?

Comment: I do not know it works great for me. no problem showing logs in logcat.

Comment: Worked ! the problem was the initializer that had to call the color method () in MainActivity. Now my problem is other... the object in Arraylist is: [D@23a4ab47